# Adding simple Geomasking (Donut masking) feature using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point, masking, affine-transformation

I would like to add a simple halo masking feature/plugin in QGIS. Halo/donut masking basically transforms (shifts) all points in a layer to a random distance between two user-provided distances. During this process, these points are also transformed at random angles (auto-generated).

Once users have loaded the shapefile as a layer, they should be able to enter a minimum and maximum distance. From within this buffer, random distances should be generated for each point to be transformed. Also, a random angle should be generated for the transformation of each point. A new layer should be created containing the masked layer.

I have written the following code but need to develop it further. How can I  transform the points into a new layer?

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QGis, QgsFeature, QgsField, QgsFields
from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter
import random

user_defined_minimum = 100
user_defined_maximum = 200

original_layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feature in original_layer.getFeatures():
    point = feature.geometry().asPoint()
    x, y = point.x(), point.y()
    print(str(x) + " " + str(y))

New_layer= processing.getObject(original_layer)
fields = QgsFields()

writer = processing.VectorWriter(output_file, None, fields.toList(), QGis.WKBMultiPolygon, New_layer.crs())

features = processing.features(New_layer)

for feat in features:
   x, y = random.uniform(1.5, 1.9) 

   writer.addFeature(feat)
```

[image]

This QGIS plugin has been requested since our MapSafe Data Sovereignty tool was released last month. MapSafe offers a complete approach for sovereign data owners to safeguard sensitive geospatial datasets by geomasking, encrypting, and notarising them from within the browser. The tool:
https://www.mapsafe.xyz

More details are here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/tgis.13094  (pdf)

The masking aspect is shown in a video here: https://www.mapsafe.xyz/safeguarding-guide.html
Dataset link: https://mapsafe.xyz/all_clusters_kamloops.zip

In comparison to plugins on affine transformations, this plugin should be very simple.

Comment: Where do you generate the random distance and direction? Or are you expecting someone else to code this for you? The way things work here, you make a best effort and we point out the mistake, but if you don't make any effort, why should we?

Comment: I am new to QGIS and Python.

Comment: I have added some code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Preamble*: Unfortunatelly I did not read your articles, but I hope I understood your issue correctly.

Let's assume there is an input point layer called *'points2'*, see the image below.

[image: input]

The task is the same as yours *to transform (shift) all points in a layer to a random distance between two user-provided distances and transform at a random angle (auto-generated).*

### Solution 1 : Projected Coordinate System

#### It uses [`translate()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#ae3338d8a5eea393e2da89dee5f26ee96) method of the `QgsGeometry` class

The code below also utilizes two Python packages: [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) and [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

In this example, I am working with [EPSG:5348](https://epsg.org/crs_5348/POSGAR-2007-Argentina-6.html) which is a Projected Coordinate System.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from random import uniform
from math import pi, sin, cos
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsGeometry, QgsFeature, QgsProject

def geomasking(geom: QgsGeometry, min_distance: float = 0.0, max_distance: float = 10.0) -> QgsGeometry:
    """
    Only for Projected Coordinate System !
    Translates point geometry at a random angle and random distance within a range [min_distance : max_distance]
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param geom: the feature's geometry
    :param min_distance: the minimum distance
    :param max_distance: the maximum distance
    """
    angle = uniform(0, 2*pi)
    distance = uniform(min_distance, max_distance)
    dx = distance * cos(angle)
    dy = distance * sin(angle)
    geom.translate(dx, dy)

    return geom

# referring to the original point layer
input_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points2")[0]

# creating a new layer for the output
output_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"Point?crs={input_layer.crs().authid()}&index=yes", "geomask", "memory")

# accessing output layer provider
provider = output_layer.dataProvider()
# inheriting data from the original layer
provider.addAttributes(input_layer.fields())
output_layer.updateFields()

# processing new features
for feat in input_layer.getFeatures():
    # providing geometry
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_geom = geomasking(feat.geometry())
    new_feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
    # providing attributes
    new_feat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
    # adding new feature to the output layer
    provider.addFeature(new_feat)

# adding new layer to the map
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)
```

### Solution 2 : Spherical Coordinate System

#### It uses [`computeSpheroidProject()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsDistanceArea.html#ab6f714c5ca21a254a191dd2dfc087bd3) method of the `QgsDistanceArea` class

The code below also utilizes two Python packages: [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) and [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

In this example, I am working with [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html) which is a Geographic/Spherical Coordinate System.

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```py
# imports
from math import pi
from random import uniform
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsGeometry, QgsFeature, QgsProject, QgsDistanceArea

def geomasking(geom: QgsGeometry, min_distance: float = 0.0, max_distance: float = 10.0) -> QgsGeometry:
    """
    Only for Spherical Coordinate System !
    Translates point geometry at a random angle and random distance within a range [min_distance : max_distance]
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param geom: the feature's geometry
    :param min_distance: the minimum distance
    :param max_distance: the maximum distance
    """
    angle = uniform(0, 2 * pi)
    distance = uniform(min_distance, max_distance)

    da = QgsDistanceArea()
    da.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
    new_point = da.computeSpheroidProject(geom.asPoint(), distance, angle)

    return QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(new_point)

# referring to the original point layer
input_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points2")[0]

# creating a new layer for the output
output_layer = QgsVectorLayer(f"Point?crs={input_layer.crs().authid()}&index=yes", "geomask", "memory")

# accessing output layer provider
provider = output_layer.dataProvider()
# inheriting data from the original layer
provider.addAttributes(input_layer.fields())
output_layer.updateFields()

# processing new features
for feat in input_layer.getFeatures():
    # providing geometry
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_geom = geomasking(feat.geometry())
    new_feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
    # providing attributes
    new_feat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
    # adding new feature to the output layer
    provider.addFeature(new_feat)

# adding new layer to the map
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(output_layer)
```

Change the inputs in the function if necessary (the default distance varies between 0 and 10). Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like this:

[image: result]

*Addendum:* Make yourself also familiar with [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae).

---

**References:**

- [Rotating features with multiple geometries in one layer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462260/rotating-features-with-multiple-geometries-in-one-layer-using-pyqgis/462261#462261)
- [Creating new layer with all attributes inherited from original layer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429034/creating-new-layer-with-all-attributes-inherited-from-original-layer-using-pyqgi)
- [Azimuth calculations using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349662/azimuth-calculations-pyqgis)
- [Extracting x,y coordinates from QgsGeometry: Point(x, y) using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380783/extracting-x-y-coordinates-from-qgsgeometry-pointx-y-using-pyqgis/380788#380788)
- [Difference between QgsPoint, QgsPointXY and QgsGeometry.fromPointXY() in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377881/whats-the-difference-between-qgspoint-qgspointxy-and-qgsgeometry-frompointxyq)
- [Vincenty or (Project + Euclidean) for accurate distances](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179642/vincenty-or-project-euclidean-for-accurate-distances)

Comment: Thank you so much - I am really grateful. I run the script on my dataset (see dataset link in post) but I get the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'crs'". But the dataset has crs. See error output here https://mapsafe.xyz/masking_output.png

Comment: you probably forgot `[0]` in `input_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("all_clusters_kamloops")[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now!
Forgot to add the [0]